# Ways to make most gold as a jewel crafter or leather worker

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have 525 in JC and 525 in leather working on my character. I'm interested in trying to churn some profit from the costs it took for me to get here. Is there currently a strategy or particular recipe(s) that are most profitable in the auction house? Would you other crafters be able to suggest the cheapest gems to perhaps cut or leather based gear to make that will return the most profit for least amount of work?

Comment: This information changes on an almost daily basis. What is popular now may not be popular tomorrow. This also varies on a per-realm basis based on fluctuating markets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you'd have to do research on for your particular realm.  Every server is different, although there are some things that are static.  Red gem cuts (Brilliant, Bold, Delicate) tend to always sell very well, as they are used by anyone who knows what they're doing when it comes to picking gems.  There are a few others that are widely used, but that depends on how active your server is and how many JC's are targeting the same gem.  The red gems tend to sell the best since they are so widely used that it doesn't matter if there are multiple JC's selling them.  If you want to go for larger profits per item, look into investing in a popular cut for epic gems.  Jewelcrafting is one of the most lucrative professions in the game, but it doesn't turn large profits per item sold.  You're going to have to do a lot of buying, prospecting, researching, cutting, and selling to establish a solid career.

As for Leatherworking, it's a little harder to pinpoint demand, but people are always in need of leg armor, and gathering the mats as a LW isn't that difficult.  It should be noted that buying the raw mats on the AH are sometimes cheaper than the asking price of leg armor.

For further research based on your realm, learn to use the [Auctioneer](http://auctioneeraddon.com) add-on and/or browse server AH stats on [The Undermine Journal](http://theunderminejournal.com).

Comment: You will also find that at this stage of WoW the mats for most items are more expensive than the items crafted. Farming the mats your self is not cost effective either as the time spent farming mats could have been spend on other tasks making gold directly. Most gold I made is from gathering professions or combination of secondary profession perks, such as Disenchanting and Prospecting. As servers mature and new items grow old the gold income dwindles and unless you are online 3-4 times a day re-listing competitive cheap items on AH or farm raids for rep and rare patterns its not an easy task.

Comment: Come new release what usually happens is similar to: Glyphs and mats will be the gold makers. Glyphs for obvious reasons and you want to have 300-500 on AH at any one time to make a good profit during the rush (AddOns for that). Mats sell like mad for huge OTT prices at start as the dudes wanting to race to max prof level will spare no cost. Then when the dust settles the gem market will start to flourish along with most crafted PvP gear to get that easy to buy iLevel. Just make sure you get involved at the right time with the right profession :)